# pyspark: combine rows of DataFrame into DenseVector

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` with two columns:

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (1, 'a'), (2, 'a'),
    (3, 'b'), (4, 'b'),
    (5, 'c'), (6, 'c'),
    (7, 'd'), (8, 'd'),
], schema=['value', 'name'])
```

Edit 2017/01/13:
I derive this dataframe from a SQL table based on the Entity-Attribute-Value model. So an additional third entity column "id" would be available for each row.

I want to transform it into a "features" `DataFrame` as required by classifiers of the `ml` package. For individual columns this can be achieved using the `VectorAssembler`:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['value'], outputCol="features")
selected_features = assembler.transform(df).select('features')
selected_features.collect()

[Row(features=DenseVector([1.0])),
 Row(features=DenseVector([2.0])),
 Row(features=DenseVector([3.0])),
 Row(features=DenseVector([4.0])),
 Row(features=DenseVector([5.0])),
 Row(features=DenseVector([6.0])),
 Row(features=DenseVector([7.0])),
 Row(features=DenseVector([8.0]))]
```

What I want is this:

```py
[Row(features=DenseVector([1.0, 2.0])),
 Row(features=DenseVector([3.0, 4.0])),
 Row(features=DenseVector([5.0, 6.0])),
 Row(features=DenseVector([7.0, 8.0]))]
```

What would be the most efficient way to combine the values of column `value` into a `DenseVector` based on the values of column `name`?

I was thinking for example of a custom aggregation function for [GroupedData](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData) that would work with `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('name').vector_agg().collect()
```

similar to the PostgreSQL [array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) function:

```sql
SELECT array_agg(df.value) FROM table as df
GROUP BY df.name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is ill-defined, because for a fixed `name` there is no way to know which `value` belongs in which column. The classifiers in the `ml` package will all require that each column is used consistently between training samples. In your example the columns happen to be provided in the desired order, but in practice you can't rely on this.

Your problem can be solved if you can give your features indices and start with something like this:

```
df = sc.sql.createDataFrame([
    ('a', ('f1', 1)), ('a', ('f2', 2)),
    ('b', ('f1', 3)), ('b', ('f2', 4)),
    ('c', ('f1', 5)), ('c', ('f2', 6)),
    ('d', ('f1', 7)), ('d', ('f2', 8)),
], schema=['name', 'feature'])
```

First, group by `name` and aggregate your features as a list:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.groupBy('name')\
  .agg(F.collect_list('feature'))\
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+----+---------------------+
|name|collect_list(feature)|
+----+---------------------+
|   d|     [[f1,7], [f2,8]]|
|   c|     [[f1,5], [f2,6]]|
|   b|     [[f1,3], [f2,4]]|
|   a|     [[f1,1], [f2,2]]|
+----+---------------------+
```

Next, use a udf in `withColumn` to convert this array into a DenseVector. Putting it all together:

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

list_to_dense = F.udf(lambda l: Vectors.dense([v for (k,v) in sorted(l)]), VectorUDT())

df.groupBy('name')\
  .agg(F.collect_list('features'))\
  .withColumn('features', list_to_dense('collect_list(features)'))\
  .select('features')\
  .collect()
```

Output:

```
[Row(features=DenseVector([7.0, 8.0])),
 Row(features=DenseVector([5.0, 6.0])),
 Row(features=DenseVector([3.0, 4.0])),
 Row(features=DenseVector([1.0, 2.0]))]
```

Comment: You are right! The problem was related to dealing with a SQL table based on the Entity–Attribute–Value model. So there would be a third entity column. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: `collect_list` is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

From your data structure you just need to do a `join` with the same table and `filter` those rows where `values` are the same (or inverted).

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    (1, 'a'), (2, 'a'),
    (3, 'b'), (4, 'b'),
    (5, 'c'), (6, 'c'),
    (7, 'd'), (8, 'd'),
], schema=['value', 'name'])

xf = df.select(df["name"].alias("nam"), df["value"].alias("val"))
pf = df.join(xf, df["name"] == xf["nam"], "inner").where(xf["val"] < df["value"]).select(df["value"], xf["val"], df["name"])

from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler


assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['value', "val"], outputCol="features")
selected_features = assembler.transform(pf).select('features')
selected_features.collect()


#[Row(features=DenseVector([2.0, 1.0])),
# Row(features=DenseVector([4.0, 3.0])),
# Row(features=DenseVector([6.0, 5.0])),
# Row(features=DenseVector([8.0, 7.0]))]
```

Comment: This works fine for the very simple example I provided, but I'm looking for a more general approach. I refined my question.